# How to form a tree that represents the inheritance tree of an interface?

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

I know how to get all interfaces of T using `typeof(T).GetInterfaces()` but I need the exact inheritance tree.
Is it possible to resolve this somehow from the existing reflection API?

EDIT:
Allow me to clarify:

```
interface Base1 {}
interface Base2 {}
interface Foo : Base1
interface Final : Foo, Base2
```

I would like to form a tree that represents the hierarchy of Final.
I already have a dependency on NGenerics so using it for tree implementation is not a problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give a concrete example?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. As far as I know, there's no BCL way to *only* get the interfaces that are actually implemented on a specific type but exclude any interfaces that type inherited. So we'll have to roll our own:

```
public static Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> GetInterfaceHierarchyMap(this Type type)
{
    List<Type> typeAncestry = new List<Type>();
    Type ancestor = type;
    while(ancestor != null)
    {
        typeAncestry.Add(ancestor);
        ancestor = ancestor.BaseType;
    }
    Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Type>> interfaceMaps = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<Type>>();
    foreach(Type childType in typeAncestry.Reverse<Type>())
    {
        var mappedInterfaces = interfaceMaps.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);
        var allInterfacesToPoint = childType.GetInterfaces();
        interfaceMaps.Add(childType, allInterfacesToPoint.Except(mappedInterfaces));
    }
    return interfaceMaps;
}
```

One step at a time:

1. We start from the current type and walk up the [BaseType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx) until we reach the root type.
2. We reverse the list, so when we iterate over it we start with the root type first.
3. For each type down the chain, we get all interfaces applied to that type and inherited from ancestor types, then we use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) to eliminate all the ones we already found in previous iterations.

This will treat duplicate interface requirements as superfluous - i.e., if one of your ancestor types implements IDisposable and your type does as well, only the earliest implementation will be counted.

A hypothetical result of this method would be a dictionary that looks something like:

```
[object] - []
[BaseBaseClass] - [ISomeInterface]
[BaseClass] - [IAnotherInterface, IOneMore]
[ConcreteClass] - [IYetAnother]
```

Comment: Nice. But what if I am dealing with interfaces only? Does it matter? Actually it does because it doesn't have a base type.

Comment: @the_drow not sure what you mean. Interfaces can't inherit from anything so there's no hierarchy.

Comment: @Rex M, Interfaces can inherit from other interfaces which can create a hierarchy.

Comment: @Sam interfaces can *require* other interfaces. That is not the same as inheritance.

Comment: @Rex M, actually, the documentation specifically uses the term inheritance. *"An interface itself can inherit from multiple interfaces"*  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Comment: My problem is that I need to find the most specific interface in my hierarchy that matches type U that doesn't inherit from T.

Comment: @SamuelNeff It doesn't say that (at least as of today it doesn't).  It says, "Interfaces can implement other interfaces." but I couldn't find the text you mentioned.

Comment: @gonzobrains are you saying the documentation changed in the last 5 years? ;)

Comment: Apparently so. Either that or I haven't had enough sleep today. :)